# Scala object not serializable

Tags: scala

I have the following data:

```
columnTypeMap: Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(STRING -> List(0, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 43, 45, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54), DECIMAL -> List(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46), INTEGER -> List(3))
```

And when I try and run it in the repl I get the following errors:

```
caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$$anon$2
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$$anon$2, value: Map(STRING -> List(0, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 43, 45, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54), DECIMAL -> List(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46), INTEGER -> List(3)))
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: columnTypeMap, type: interface scala.collection.immutable.Map)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@9688d8d)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@70c1699d)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@41bccb00)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@779fa7ac)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@2345d2a9)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC@4b44406f)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC@592bee1c)
    - field (class: $iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC, $iwC@5356bd08)
    - field (class: $line23.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iwC)
    - object (class $line23.$read, $line23.$read@71ba0aab)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL67, type: class $line23.$read)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@5f321399)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@298ff971)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
    ... 49 more
```

What is the best solution to work around this? Why would my Map not be serlizable?

Comment: Put it inside a jar file and load that, then it should be serializable.

Comment: Is the only issue that its repl vs executable jar?

Comment: The jar doesn't need to be executable. You can just load it as a library.